# Is highlighted wall load bearing?

Tags: walls, load-bearing

I was hoping someone could tell me if the circled wall is load bearing?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: It’s impossible to say without being on site and looking above and below the room, but if it looks like it’s roughly in-line with the back of a fireplace/chimney on the other side of the room, then it probably is load bearing. When was the building built and what is the renovation history?  Is it an apartment building or house?

Comment: Its an apartment building and was built in 2001 @RibaldEddie

Comment: You should be able to get structural drawings from your local planning office?

Comment: @RibaldEddie could you tell me a bit more about what you mean by local planning office? Would that be a government run facility in the town/ city?

Comment: Yes. Assuming you live in a modern western democracy, there should be drawings that were submitted as part of the permitting process.

Comment: Or you could just hire a structural engineer to come and advise?

Comment: @RibaldEddie I live in Texas, USA ill try to see if I can find them at local government office thank you

Comment: A picture of the building from the outside would help, with a cue as to how the picture relates to the drawing.

Comment: You say this is an apartment building.  Are you the owner or a tenant?  What are you planning to do to the wall

Comment: It depends on the roof framing.